# How can I merge a contact between the phone only list and my Google account?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, google-contacts, huawei-u8850

I managed to create a phone-only contact which was then linked to the contact's Facebook account. I've also got a Google contact for the same person which has additional contact information in it.

I'd like to merge the contacts so that I only have one entry for this person but with the combined information. I don't want to have to copy the information manually between the accounts.

The phone is running Android version 2.3.7 and it's the contacts manager that came with the phone.

I've checked the similar questions, bit none seems to address my specific issue.

Comment: Android version? And do you know what contact manager app you are using?

Comment: @Caleb - I've updated the question.

Comment: <wince> I'm sorry I won't be of much help as I don't have a Gingerbread device around any more and my memory isn't going to serve me. Contact merge handling has been updated about 20 times since those days (mostly for the better) but it should be possible. You just have to find somebody that knows. In 'good news', with some time on seedy interwebs and help from hacked Russian ROM's you should be able to bring that device up to 4.x/Ice Cream Sandwich.